# PySQL - calculate percentage using two rows in same column

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have the below table

[image]

I want to calculate round((a/a+b)*100,2) for the value column as a separate pct column.

[image]

Tried everything possible and I need this as a single query. Not using with or not broken down as multiple queries.

Comment: Please show us the query that you have tried. Thanks. So how did you get 90 for Feb?

Comment: I tried this query and it worked. select a.month,(count/s)*100 from a join
(select month,sum(count) as s from a group by month)b on a.month= b.month
where a.value = 'a';

Answer (score 0):

This query helped me to get the desired answer.

```
select a.month,(count/s)*100 from a join
(select month,sum(count) as s from a group by month)b on a.month= b.month
where a.value = 'a';
```